# How to write AES cipher text to an image

Tags: image-processing, aes

In the process of image encryption using AES, when the pixel values are read and when the AES encryption applied, the cipher text results in some negative values. How is it possible to frame an encrypted image from these kind of negative values i.e., cipher text?

Comment: You mean the ciphertext byte values are in the range of from -128 to 127? Transform them to 0 - 255 if you need that.

Comment: Exactly....How to transform them to 0-255..?? Any ideas? I don't need code! Just an idea..

Comment: @Balaji R ..I am trying to perform AES on a RGB image. The cipher text contains lot of negative values. Since it is not possible to write encrypted image with negative values , I posted this question.

Comment: why don't you simply add 128 to all the values & write it. When reading subtract 128 from all the values!

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you. Thanks.