# Increased cipher length in Integer array AES encryption

Tags: java, image, encryption, encoding, aes

In the following code I have taken an integer array and performing the AES encryption. The input is an integer array of size 16. When I encrypt the data I get cipher byte[] size of 64. 
It is obvious that an integer occupies 4B, so 16 * 4 = 64, which is the cipher length. But if I implement the same technique on an image(512 X 512), then the cipher image size may be four times the original image!
How to have the cipher length equivalent to the plaintext length in case of an image ??

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class StreamDemo2 {
    static String IV = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
    static String encryptionKey = "0123456789abcdef";

    public static void main(String ad[])
    {
        StreamDemo2 st = new StreamDemo2();

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream (baos);
        int arr[] = new int[16];

        for(int k = 0 ; k < 16; k++)
            arr[k] = k + 11;

        for(int k = 0 ; k < 16; k++)
            System.out.println(" USER Plain text = " + arr[k]);



        try{
            for(int i = 0; i < 16;i++)
                dos.writeInt (arr[i]);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        // conversion to bytes ends here
        // Now follows the mehtod invoking
        byte[] c = null;

        try{
             c = st.encrypt(data, encryptionKey);
        }
        catch(Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Cipher length = " + c.length);

        // Now follows the code to decrypt

        byte[] d = null;

       try{
            d = st.decrypt(c, encryptionKey);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream (d);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream (bais);
        int j;

        System.out.println("Original data is : ");
        try{
            for(int k =0; k < 16; k++)
                System.out.print(dis.readInt() + "\t");
            }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] ciph, String encryptionKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    return cipher.doFinal(ciph);
  }

  public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, String encryptionKey) throws Exception{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "SunJCE");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key,new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    //return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText),"UTF-8"); // changed since the receiveing side expects the byte[]
    return cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(AES) Encryption works directly on bytes. It doesn't know anything about how big your image is or how it is encoded. That's what you have to think about. If you have a 512x512 pixel image, then you should think about how it is represented when serialized.

A pixel *usually* consists of three channels. One example is RGB (red - green - blue), others are HSL/HSV/YCrCb. A common detail depth per channel are 8 bit. So you can represent each pixel with 3 bytes. If you want to read those pixel back correctly, you should know how big the dimensions are, so you add two ints (limit on dimension) at the beginning of your image data format and you're done. This is the most basic format which will take

```
3 * 512 * 512 + 2 * 4 bytes = 786440 bytes
```

This is not a multiple of 16 bytes and therefore needs to be padded to be encrypted. This can be directly achieved by instantiating a `Cipher` which provides padding. Otherwise, you would have to do that yourself:

```
Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
```

Of course this example calculation would look different if you're having only grayscale images or a different channel depth such as 16 bit for higher quality.

When you're saying

> then the cipher image size may be four times the original image

you're comparing apples with oranges (pixels with bytes). However, you could interpret the ciphertext as image data. This is an interesting experiment. Have a look at the [ECB penguin](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022) for that.

---

Be sure to use proper randomly generated encryption keys when this is out of the testing phase. Printable keys are easier to brute-force than randomly generated ones.

Always use a fresh and randomly generated IV for each encryption. This provides semantic security.

Use authenticated encryption to prevent padding oracle attacks and detect (malicious) manipulation. This can be done with an authenticated mode like GCM or EAX, or with an encrypt-then-MAC scheme with a strong MAC function like HMAC-SHA256.

Comment: The main task is to represent cipher text in image format. That is why I am considering the the cipher text( which is in Bytes) to write an image.

Comment: You mean writing an image from arbitrary ciphertexts even if the plaintext was not an image? I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Nope... What I meant was this. I read the pixels from an image, assume I read the first row pixels of an image and perform AES encryption , I'll get the cipher text ; I'll repeat the same on every row, I have the cipher text of all the rows. Now I can't write those cipher bytes back to image because it has negative values right?? Image won't accept a negative value for its pixel...I just need to have the corresponding cipher image of a plain image! Which can be showable on a research paper..

Comment: Those aren't really negative values. It's how they are shown to you, but bytes can have values 0 to 255. Sometimes it is shown as values 128 to 255 mapped to -128 to -1, but the data inside is still the same. You haven't provided any code or a description about your actual issue and frankly this is a completely different question than the one I answered.

Comment: @Arjtom B Please check this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776494/how-to-write-aes-cipher-text-to-an-image]

Comment: Yes, that is still too broad or unclear. There are a million ways you can represent image data, so any answer that is given may not match how you represent image data and how you want to encrypt it. Where not here to make [wild guesses](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) and hope that it may help you. As we've seen in *this* question and answer, you've had something else in mind. If this doesn't help you in any way then I will delete my answer and vote to close both of your questions. If you don't want to share details then Stack Overflow is not for you.